# R looping anova and pick data frame names from list

Tags: r, variables, anova

Below is a working R script. I want to anova data frames dfa and then dfb - but 
the aov function only reads the first data frame. I have searched but not found a solution. It is more important that the script is easy to read than computing efficiency.
How can I make aov to loop through the data frames?
Thanks in advance.

```
#two dummy data frames
Obs <- c(1,2,1,4,5,6) ;Treat <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
dfa <- data.frame(Obs=Obs, Treat=Treat) 
Obs2 <- c(10,22,10,43,52,60)
dfb <- data.frame(Obs=Obs2, Treat=Treat)
Names <- c("dfa","dfb")

#  Loop here but cannot get it to work with calling data frame names just repeats first analysis - dfb has quite different values
for(i in 1:2) { 
print(summary(aov( Obs ~ Treat, data=as.data.frame(Names[i]))))  
print(Names[i])
}
```

Comment: Also, in your code, the values repeat as you created `Obs`, `Treat` objects.  The result may be from the output of `summary(aov(Obs~Treat))`  Suppose you created the dataset without creating the vector objects `dfa <- data.frame(Obs=c(1,2,1,4,5,6), Treat=c(1,1,1,2,2,2)); dfb <- data.frame(Obs=c(10,22,10,43,52,60), Treat=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))`  Upon running your loop, `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Obs' not found`

Comment: Wow that was different! In any case, both the 'function' and 'lapply' works, and I also changed the variable names to more unique names.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot - thanks a lot! Now I will try to use this knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try either

```
Map(function(x) summary(aov(Obs~Treat,data=x)) , mget(Names))
```

Or

```
lapply(mget(Names), function(x) summary(aov(Obs~Treat, data=x)))
```

If you need a function that also changes the "data" in the "Call" formula.

```
 f1 <- function(formula= as.formula('Obs~Treat'), data, ...){
   Call <- match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)
   Call[[1]] <- as.name('aov')
   Call$formula <- as.formula(terms(formula))
   Call$data <- as.symbol(substitute(nm, list(nm=data)))
   eval(Call)
  }

   Map(function(x,y) f1(data=y), mget(Names), Names)
   #$dfa
   #Call:
   #aov(formula = Obs ~ Treat, data = dfa)

   #Terms:
   #                 Treat Residuals
   #Sum of Squares  20.166667  2.666667
   #Deg. of Freedom         1         4

   #Residual standard error: 0.8164966
   #Estimated effects may be unbalanced

   #$dfb
   #Call:
   #aov(formula = Obs ~ Treat, data = dfb)

   #Terms:
   #                 Treat Residuals
   # Sum of Squares  2128.1667  240.6667
   #Deg. of Freedom         1         4

   #Residual standard error: 7.756718
   #Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```